# nginx - uWSGI HTTP + websocket config

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, uwsgi, ini

I'm trying to configure uWSGI for an application (Django) that uses http & websocket queries.
Here is the uWSGI `ini` file that I did to achieve this

```lua
[uwsgi]
ini = :runserver
ini = :wsserver

[default]
userhome = /home/myuser
virtualenv = %(userhome)/.virtualenvs/myapp
chdir = %(userhome)/Documents/myapp
master = true
no-orphans = true
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
threads = 1
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings
vacuum = true

[runserver]
ini = :default
socket = /tmp/myapp.sock
module = wsgi_django
buffer-size = 32768
processes = 4

[wsserver]
ini = :default
http-socket = /tmp/myapp_websocket.sock
module = wsgi_websocket
processes = 2
http-websockets = true
gevent = 1000
```

As you can see I'm including both my services `runserver` & `websocket` from `uwsgi`.
I see nginx and uwsgi communicating between them but nginx always returns me

> NetworkError: 502 Bad Gateway

I see no error in uwsgi log but if I comment one of them, the other works.

Can somebody help me to debug that ?

Comment: it looks like you want to spawn two unrelated instances, while effectively you are spawning a single one. Remove the [uwsgi] section and invoke 2 different instances using the uwsgi --ini file:section syntax or the Emperor

Comment: Yeah that's about what I did finally but I don't find this very maintainable. I wanted to regroup these 2 instances in one config file because they are linked to the same application, and their default values only applies to them... I though uWSGI allows to configure multiple instances in one file.

Comment: you can maintain the two configs in the same file, just ensure to spawn 2 different instances pointing to the same file but different sections

Comment: I see, as I'm in emperor mode I don't know how to specify the sections to load...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by using 2 different files and repeating the common settings on each